# function in textwrap (Expected type 'str', got 'set[int | object]' instead)

Tags: python-3.x, list, networking, sniffing

I have this function, but I am getting this error. I have tried but am not able to fix this.

```
size -= len(prefix)
    if size % 2:
        size -= 1
    return '\n'.join([prefix + line for line in textwrap.wrap({size, string})])
```

Comment: You are passing a set into textwrap when it is expecting a string. `{size,string}` is defining a set

Comment: @JohnM. I tried to change the string but the same error always i don't understand the error what it is exactly i searching in google about this error but i don't find any thing interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to do something like this:

```
import textwrap

s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
prefix = '>>> '

desired_width = 15
width_without_prefix = desired_width - len(prefix)

print('\n'.join(prefix + l for l in textwrap.wrap(s, width_without_prefix)))
```

which returns:

```
>>> abcdefghijk
>>> lmnopqrstuv
>>> wxyz
```

However, you are passing `{size, string}` as a parameter to the [textwrap.wrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) method while the wrap method expects the first parameter to be a string:

```
textwrap.wrap(text, width=70, *, initial_indent='', subsequent_indent=''
```

To illustrate this we can check the type of the object you are passing (which is a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) object):

```
v = {s, width_without_prefix}
print(type(v))
```

returns `<class 'set'>`.

As it happens, this can all be simplified if you use [`textwrap.fill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill) instead of `wrap`:

```
print(textwrap.fill(s, initial_indent=prefix, subsequent_indent=prefix, width=desired_width))
```